# background-size: cover not working on iOS

Tags: ios, css, background-image

This is my code:

```
background-color:#fff;
background-attachment:fixed;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
```

It's working on desktop, iPad and Android mobile:

[image: working]

On Chrome and Safari on iPhone, the background is too big:

[image: too big]

Comment: The `<div class="backdrop"></div>` solution worked for me by Ryan and Roko's answer. However, instead of adding `position: absolute` to the CSS block, I added this line below and worked great: > min-height: 100vh;

Answer (score 96):

This happens, particularly on iOS, when you have `background-attachment:fixed`. On mobile, I usually put `background-attachment:scroll` inside of a `@media` query.

As [@RyanKimber pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30469824/155423), fixed attached images use the whole `<body>` size. On mobile this can get really tall which blows your image out. Setting the attachment back to `scroll` allows your cover image to stretch within its own container.

Comment: When setting the max-width don't forget to account for the mobile device being in landscape orientation, otherwise the media query won't trigger when in landscape and you'll have the same problem.

Comment: If you want a solution without @media queries, then see my answer below with one simple body:after CSS rule, and no additional html node: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43058483/7765675

Comment: Almost the perfect answer for me because I don't mind switching to `background-attachment: scroll` if necessary. I just tweaked the media query to target only IOS mobile devices.

`@supports (-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch) {
 body *: {
  background-attachment: scroll;
 }
}`

I found this trick [on another stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47818418)

Answer (score 81):

Elaborating on Ryan's answer, without adding any new `html` node or using `@media` queries, **using only one css**.

> If you want to keep a `cover` sized `fixed` background on all the devices including iOS, without adding a new node, then the trick is to do **the fixed positioning on the element (body)** itself and not the background, since a fixed background and cover sizing messes up iOS.

It works in production like a charm on iOS as well: https://www.doklist.com/

This code won't work, since iOS uses the hight of the `document` and not the `viewport`:

```
body {
      background: url(https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
}
```

Now this is the magic, the `body:after` is fixed, and **not the background**:

```css
body:after{
      content:"";
      position:fixed; /* stretch a fixed position to the whole screen */
      top:0;
      height:100vh; /* fix for mobile browser address bar appearing disappearing */
      left:0;
      right:0;
      z-index:-1; /* needed to keep in the background */
      background: url(https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg) center center;
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
}
```

I could have used the **body** itself, with "position:fixed;overflow-y:scroll", but I didn't want to mess with the positioning of the body and my overall layout.

So doing this on the **body:after** is a very easy fix. I have tested the solution on Mac, and iOS with firefox, safari, chrome.

I also created a github repo with 2 examples for this: https://github.com/thesved/fixed-cover-background

Comment: It appears the body:after{...} solution works perfectly.  I just tested on browserstack.  Excellent solution!

Comment: Be sure to add background-attachment:scroll for pesky iphone background zoom-in

Comment: The example on your github repo doesn't seem to be working with the iOS12 simulator using an iPad Pro in landscape.

Comment: GitHub repo worked great... tested on 2020 SE+ phones.

Comment: Thank you! If you are using Scss or Sass, you can make a mixin and include it on the element that you want. If you want a background color while loading, set the element's `background-color` on the mixin to transparent and add these ruler on `&:after` block.

Comment: The best solution I've come across. Tested on Chrome Win 10, iOS 14 and Chrome Android 11, and it works perfectly. Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 16):

Here's an easy workaround so that the pictures in Safari browsers can be displayed normally (scroll only in Safari browsers instead of fixed in other media)

```
@supports ( -webkit-touch-callout : none) {
.selector {
background-attachment:scroll
}
}

@supports not ( -webkit-touch-callout : none) {
.selector {
background-attachment: fixed;
}
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This caused me a number of problems as well. The problem is that iOS is using the full height & width of the body instead of the viewport to decide the size.

Our solution was to create a new `<div class="backdrop"></div>`.

We apply the background to this `div` and give it `position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0`.

Since this div is now the size of the viewport, `background-size: cover` works just fine.

Comment: These values actually create an element the size of the whole body, and not the viewport, which recreates the original problem

Answer (score 1):

Change **background-attatchment** from **fixed** to **scroll**.

```
.yourClass {
    background-attachment: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.imageDiv {
    background: url('image.jpg') center center no-repeat fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}

@supports (-webkit-touch-callout: none) {
    .imageDiv {
        background: url('image.jpg') center top no-repeat scroll;
        background-size: auto 100vh;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This post answers your questions: [why does CSS background-size: cover not work in portrait mode on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12599234/why-does-css-background-size-cover-not-work-in-portrait-mode-on-ios)

Not all browsers recognize the cover keyword for background-size, and as a result, simply ignore it.

So we can overcome that limitation by setting the background-size to 100% width or height, depending on the orientation. We can target the current orientation (as well as the iOS device, using device-width). With these two points I think you can use CSS background-size:cover on iOS in portrait-mode

See that post for more resources.

Answer (score 0):

[Broken background image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cASfg.png)

You can also try

```
background-size: contain;
```

[fixed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVMML.png)

if it works for you as it worked for me,
Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
background: url( /gfx/background.jpg  ) no-repeat top center fixed; 
background-size: 100vmax 100vmax;
```

As mentioned before, "cover" will cover document height, not view height. Most of the units will not work as expected hence vmax.

Not really cover, does the job with squared images :)