# CSS3 Fixed Background not working on mobile devices - video background possible?

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml

Using a fixed css3 background images works fine for the desktop (Chrome, Firefox, IE/Edge no issues), it stays always at the screen with full-height and width bg.
Unfortunately it does not work on mobile devices. Tablets and phones with Android are unable to fix the image in the background.
Is there a way to check the device height/width to load different media or is it possible to simply zoom or scale the image automatically? Are there maybe any JS kits to accomplish this.

Moreover I plan to embed a background video (webm), does this work on mobile devices? May I ask to check if there is way, the video background loads only with WiFi connection. Otherwise it shall be a static image.

Comment: Detecting device dimensions is possible with media queries. I recommend to post code to get best answers. Another important information is the browser that is used on Android.

Comment: Standard chrome latest version / Android.

Comment: According to http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-attachment background-attachment does not work on Chrome on Android, but there is already a question targeting it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38517364/background-attachment-fixed-not-working-on-android-ios.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, any change to use webm backgrounds on Android Web App?