# background-attachment image: fixed not working on mobile

Tags: html, css

I am building a website where I want the background image to be attached fixed.
I have achieved this in desktop browsers with the CSS below, but it doesn't work on Smartphone.
This is a known bug with background-attachment: fixed. 
I don't know how to fix it.

```
#page-header{
  height: 300px;
  background: url("../img/wood.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px #eee solid;
  padding-top: 50px;
}
```

My HTML

```
<header id="page-header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3 text-center">
        <h1 id="h1header">Products</h1>
        <p>Local, Organic, Tasty</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

You can find my website at http://maisonbergeret.com/product.html

My question is how can I keep the exact same effect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23236158/how-to-replicate-background-attachment-fixed-on-ios) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38517364/background-attachment-fixed-not-working-on-android-ios) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26372127/background-fixed-no-repeat-not-working-on-mobile)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [background: fixed no repeat not working on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26372127/background-fixed-no-repeat-not-working-on-mobile)

Comment: Thank you for the link but it doesn't have the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I changed for page-header.

```
#page-header:before{
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position: fixed;
  background: url("../img/wood.jpg")no-repeat center center;
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px #eee solid;
  padding-top: 50px;
  z-index: -10;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Below the header, I have a section product with id="products"

```
section#products{
    background-color: #FAEBD7;
}
```

Same color as my body background-color: #FAEBD7;

Adjusted margins and now it works.