# Hosted basic website and it doesn't look the same as tested on computer

Tags: html, css

Im a beginner. I was creating my portfolio website. It looks good on computer and when I'm testing it for smaller devices on my computer everything works fine.

But only I hosted it and opened a link on my phone my background picture which should be fixed and centered and text float over it when scrolling (this is a way it works on computer) but on the phone pic is only partial, zoomed and scrolls together with text. I don't know what did I miss or did wrong.

Please someone give an advice.

```css
.bg-img {
    background-image: url("images/colors4.png");
    min-height: 720px;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
.wrapper {
    background: url('images/colors4.png') no-repeat   center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

.profile-picture {
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
.page-introduction {
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
.icons {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
.col-sm-6 {
    padding-left: 80px;
    padding-right: 80px;
}

.skills-list {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 200px;
}

.scroll {
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 100px
}

#toTopBtn {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 26px;
    right: 39px;
    z-index: 98;
    padding: 21px;
    background-color: rgba(198, 84, 232, 0.8)
}

.js .cd-top--fade-out {
    opacity: .5
}

.js .cd-top--is-visible {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1
}

.js .cd-top {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .3s, visibility .3s, background-color .3s
}

.cd-top {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05) !important;
    background: url(https://res.cloudinary.com/dxfq3iotg/image/upload/v1571057658/cd-top-arrow.svg) no-repeat center 50%;
    background-color: rgba(198, 84, 232, 0.8);
}
```

```html
   <div class="bg-img wrapper img-fluid">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Welcome to my portfolio</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#about-me">About me</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#skills">My skills</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#projects">My projects</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#contact-me">Contact me</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <a href="#" id="toTopBtn" class="cd-top text-replace js-cd-top cd-top--is-visible cd-top--fade-out" data-abc="true"></a>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-6 profile-picture">
            <img src="me2.png" class="mx-auto d-block img-fluid profile-picture" alt="profile piture">
            <h1>Inna</h1>
            <p class="title">Front end web developer</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 page-introduction">
            <h2 id="about-me">
                Responsive Front-end Development
            </h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam, praesentium! Incidunt totam dignissimos deserunt eius ea, aliquid corrupti necessitatibus, sit id consectetur ipsum velit vitae ut asperiores? Repellat, dolor eos?.</p>
          </div> 
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: You should make your website responsive. You could use `@media` query for it. Link to a tutorial https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: `but on the phone pic is only partial, zoomed and scrolls together with text` your problem is that `background-attachment: fixed` is [not supported well](https://caniuse.com/background-attachment) on mobile, especially not on iOS.

Comment: I tried @media and it didn't work. Issue was the same - on computer everything is fine but on the phone no. But when I removed fixed position for the background everything looks good now. And maybe it's not exactly what I wanted but at list the background is not partial or zoomed anymore. Looks beautiful. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [background attachment: fixed not working on android/ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38517364/background-attachment-fixed-not-working-on-android-ios)