# Background-Attachment: Fixed Doesn't Work On iOS

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, background-attachment

I'm trying to find a solution to the problem I'm having with fixed backgrounds on iOS devices. I would rather not have to redesign everything for this website, and I'm hoping that some CSS changes can fix it. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yxa22.jpg) is what the site looks like on iPhones, and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhcan.jpg) is what it should look like. The CSS code I'm using is as follows:

```
.container {
    min-width: 320px;
    max-width: 480px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.fixed-background {
    height: 800px;
    -webkit-backgound-size: cover;
    -o-backgound-size: cover;
    -moz-backgound-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

I've also tried using a `@media` query to fix it for iOS using some posts on stackoverflow, but this didn't seem to have any effect:

```
@media screen and (min-color-index:0) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    .fixed-background {
        background-attachment: scroll;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="fixed-background bg-1">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="title">
            <h1>ROOK PROPERTY<br>MANAGEMENT INC.</h1>
            <h2>CONDOMINIUM MANAGEMENT</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23236158/how-to-replicate-background-attachment-fixed-on-ios

Comment: After some debate, I ended up just using position: scroll for the mobile css. Thanks for the information.

Comment: I think this answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24154666/background-image-size-cover-not-working-on-ios/43058483#43058483

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fixed background image with ios7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20443574/fixed-background-image-with-ios7)

Comment: Where is the code for the class .iparaxify?

Answer (score 5):

I just went through the same issue, and this is how I solved it.

First, you need to declare your body and html to be 100% wide and 100% tall:

```css
html, body{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
```

Then, the scrolling on your page can NOT be done by the body: you must wrap it on a container. This container needs three parameters: overflow:scroll, width: 100% and height: 100%. I recommend wrapping the entire site in it:

```css
#wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
 }
```

If you don't like how it scrolls, you can also try adding 
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch.

Hope that helps you/whoever comes looking for this!

Comment: Solution didn't work for me. Also be aware that this solution will potentially create problems with other scrolling effects

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will help
I found a general solution for Background Position Fixed on iOS.

And it works really well with recent iPads.

Feel free to copy!

Just beneath the body tag add a

`<div id="iPad"></div>`

Then style that as:

```
div#iPad { 
    position: sticky; 
    background: <your image + settings>; 
    top: 0; 
    margin: 0; 
    height: 100vh; 
    margin-top: -100vh; 
    z-index: -1 }
```

I put it on all pages of my site.
But you can see it in action on this [really long music page](https://www.whitelightproduction.com/uk-music-producer-london/).

It works!!

Took me a while to come up with this.

Note you can only see this on iOS tablet.
I didn't implement it for mobiles.
But possible the code would work just as well.

Answer (score -2):

To all my div with fixed background I add the classes `class="parallax iparaxify paraxify"`
And in my main css file I have:

```
.parallax {
width: 100%;
background url(../images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

And finally make it parallax for everything except i products

```
.paraxify {
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

At the end deactivate `position:fixed` for ipad, iphone and ipod with jquery

```
// adds mobile class, and mobile os to html tag
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
var deviceAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();

if (deviceAgent.match(/(iphone|ipod|ipad)/)) {
$('.iparaxify').removeClass('paraxify');
}
});
```