# background-size: cover sizing issue with iOS devices

Tags: html, ios, css, web

I am using this CSS to create a parallax effect with images that are the background of section elements.

```
background-image: url(./../img/intro.png);
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed !important;
background-size: cover !important;
```

When I view the site on iPads or iPhones the images are crazy zoomed in and distorted. Research would have me believe that on these devices the images are being stretched to the size of the body. I have tried so many fixes from various forums etc but to no avail. I am really surprised there is no concrete fix for this as it seems quite common.

Comment: Look here, I think it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24154666/background-image-size-cover-not-working-on-ios/43058483#43058483