# How to change background image for the css tag "body:after"

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to change my html body background image

```
<style> 
body:after{
  content:"";
  position:fixed; /* stretch a fixed position to the whole screen */
  top:0;
  height:100vh; /* fix for mobile browser address bar appearing disappearing */
  left:0;
  right:0;
  z-index:-1; /* needed to keep in the background */
  background: url("img/001.jpg") center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
```

}

I've tried `$('body').css('background-image', 'url(img/002.jpg)')` with no luck

Thank you very much

Comment: Why on earth would anyone use body:after? I would really like to know...

Comment: You can't target a pseudo element in JavaScript because it's not part of the DOM

Comment: The code is running fine probably, but your DOM is completely loaded by then, so no "Visible" changes occur... Please give some more context on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @LironNavon to avoid using an extra element. I do this a lot.

Comment: regarding this topic 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43058483/773406 
I want to centre background image of the html body and change it later!

Comment: The question is not why use pseudo-elements, but why use pseudo-elements on the body? it seems very weird for me...

Comment: @LironNavon for the same purpose of using pseudo element on any element: avoiding extra element. Suppose you want to have a blurred or rotated background image on your body, how you will do it?