# CSS: Background not showing up iPhone or iPad but works on iMac ( Safari )

Tags: css, ios, iphone, ipad, background

I've got a full width hero background that is working properly on every browser we tested except for Safari on iPhone and iPad. It does work on iMac Safari.
On iPhone and iPad it doesn't appear.
Here's the code:

```
.hero {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 600px;
    background-image: url('../images/heroFullScreen.jpg');
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

You can view the site here: https://sanitonplastic.ca to recreate the problem if you've got one of the devices.

Really hope someone can help, we're supposed to be going live tomorrow.

Thank you!

Comment: The image does not appear in chrome. But on safari it appears: the

In chrome it doesn't appear because you have this `fadeonload` class here `container-fluid hero`

However, check this out - https://stackoverflow.com/a/31445503/8098173

Comment: IOS Safari does not support background-attachment fixed, see [link]https://caniuse.com/?search=background%20attachment

Answer (score 0):

martinho and A Haworth were correct. I used a media query for mobile view and set `background-attachment: scroll` which solved the problem, although lost parallax.