# background-size: cover not working on mobile screens

Tags: css, reactjs, mobile, frontend, background-image

I'm trying to have a background-image cover the entire viewport for mobile devices for my React project.

- model: iPhone 11
- os: 16.5.1

I've noticed 2 issues:

1)

When I set the `background-color` of a `<body>` tag => it covers the entire screen

[image]

```
@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
  body {
    background-color: blue;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;

  }
}
```

BUT, when I use a `background-image` to set the background it does not

[image]

```
@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
  body {
    background-color: blue;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;

  }
}
```

2. 

When I try to set any `background` property, for any sort of child element of the `<body>` tag to cover the entire screen => it doesn't work

- child div with a `background-color`

[image]

```
@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
  body {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}

#app {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

-child div with a`background-image`

[image]

```
@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
  body {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}

#app {
  background-image: url("https://res.cloudinary.com/ducqdbpaw/image/upload/v1685200227/FABIO/2017/Sanzogni_Significance_14_36_x_48_silver_leaf_oil_on_canvas_mouygv.jpg")
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

I've re-adjusted my css rules many times according to some sources I've found:

- [background-size: cover not working on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24154666/background-size-cover-not-working-on-ios)

=>

```
@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
  body {
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-image: url("image url");
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

... same issue

- https://gist.github.com/yang-wei/9114967

=>

```
@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
  body {
    background-image: url("https://res.cloudinary.com/ducqdbpaw/image/upload/v1685200227/FABIO/2017/Sanzogni_Significance_14_36_x_48_silver_leaf_oil_on_canvas_mouygv.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

..shows no image

Ultimately, I want this image to cover the entire background. Either through the `<body>` tag or the `<App/>` tag for my React project. Any ideas?

the html of my app

[image]

- **Reproducible example:**

https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-architecture-s4s96n?file=/src/styles.css&resolutionWidth=320&resolutionHeight=675

Comment: Does setting `min-height: 100vh;` on the `<body>` tag makes the image take the whole space?

Comment: What meta settings do you have? Please put a runnable snippet into your question to make it easier for us to test. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I’ve just noticed that in the image of your code you have at least one div outside the body element.

Comment: And it looks as though it’s covering things to me. What’s the image actually look like, in terms of that blue?

Comment: Ah, I think I’ve just understood - you want the blue from the image to go right to the top, is that correct? At the moment the blue seen at the very top is from the background-color..

Comment: @LightningMcQueen Sadly it does not

Comment: @AHaworth
Sorry, it's difficult to make this reproducible because this white bar at the top of the screen only shows up on mobile devices, not on a desktop monitor

Comment: @AHaworth
That is correct, I want the image to cover that blue bar on the top of the screen, which is in fact the background-color of the body element...I should've used another color

Comment: Sadly I do not think you can do this -the best you can do is take the topmost color from the background-image and use it as background-color.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple. Just use `background` instead of `background-image` like this otherwise it will not render the image in some cases.

In a background property you can add background-color , repeat , no-repeat and other image attributes, but in the background-image property you are only allowed to add image nothing else.

And that top area of the mobile can't be replaced with a website body background image.

```
body{
    background: url("https://res.cloudinary.com/ducqdbpaw/image/upload/v1685200227/FABIO/2017/Sanzogni_Significance_14_36_x_48_silver_leaf_oil_on_canvas_mouygv.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
      body {
        background: url("https://res.cloudinary.com/ducqdbpaw/image/upload/v1685200227/FABIO/2017/Sanzogni_Significance_14_36_x_48_silver_leaf_oil_on_canvas_mouygv.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you *sure* that your answer is going to fix the problem? If yes, how?

Comment: Yes, it works. I tested it.

Comment: In a background property you can add background-color , repeat , no-repeat and other image attributes, but in the background-image property you are only allowed to add image

Comment: That's true, but that's what the user did. They've only added an image in `background-image`, and all their CSS code is correct (that's what I see). So there's no difference between `background` and `background-image` beside that you can use all `background-` properties in `background`, but obviously, that's not the case here. Unless you have an explanation for why `background` can work, and not `background-image`, this answer is incorrect (doesn't solve the problem - specifically doesn't do anything). Happy to be corrected.

Comment: No, you didn't get the issue. When he is using "background-image" he has to remove "no-repeat center center fixed" these details from the end of the property value. Then it works too.

Comment: In what way is the result you are getting any different from that given in the question?

Comment: The way OP was trying was not getting the image rendered. That's the problem.

Comment: The image is rendered but actually your solution is slightly worse than the result shown in the question as you haven’t set a blue background which goes to the top of the screen.

Comment: @Md.RakibulIslam
Sadly using background instead of background image still gives me the same issue. The image isn't covering that top bar.

Comment: @AHaworth I added codesanbox.io reproducible example in the question description

Comment: @Md.RakibulIslam Your solution works in the codesanbox.io simulation mobile viewport but not on an actual mobile device screen

Comment: I think that is a margin area of the mobile browser/ the mobile device itself. It is not any webpage background color. I am not sure but please try other webpages in your mobile browser because in my mobile I have the same shape at the top and that color is same for all webpages as it is not the webpage background color.

Comment: @Md.RakibulIslam
I think you might be right....but if that is a margin area, then why does it change color when I set the background color of the body tag of my webpage? This is proven with my first image, where that top "bar" area next to the camera lens is uniformly the same color as the rest of the screen.

Comment: @Md.RakibulIslam
I've tested this out with other colors as well...same result, this just doesn't seem to work when I use an image. 
Same example but with a yellow background color: https://res.cloudinary.com/ducqdbpaw/image/upload/v1688263996/Screen_Shot_2023-07-01_at_21.10.23_u58pso.jpg

Comment: @Md.RakibulIslam https://res.cloudinary.com/ducqdbpaw/image/upload/v1688264346/Screen_Shot_2023-07-01_at_21.10.23_whz1eo.jpg

Comment: Yes, background-color will go under the status bar at the top of a 'real' IOS device, but background-image won't. This answer does nothing and perhaps should be removed?